# SharePoint 2013 - Error "init.js failed to load"

Tags: javascript, 2013

I am new to SharePoint 2013 server and SharePoint designer 2013. When I browse SharePoint site in IE, I am getting the below error.

```
"init.js failed to load"
```

But when I browse SharePoint site in chrome, it is working fine.

Can any one help me to resolve this error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I can't find the Office Diagnostic Tool in Sharepoint 2013. Sometimes I get this error "failed to load init.js” or “failed to load start.js" in IE and Chrome as well is really bad :( .

Answer (score 1):

I ran the Office Diagnostic Tool from my PC, and the issue is resolved.

Link : http://sharepointnuke.blogspot.in/2012/05/initjs-error-with-internet-explorer.html